# how to make fragments movable in runtime

Tags: android, xml, layout

hey guys i trying to make one of the fragment movable during runtime so that i can work on other fragments by keeping aside.following is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
```

//this fragment needs to be movable

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.95"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment2"
            android:name="com.harshal.fragments.Fragment2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="11.02" >

            <!-- Preview: layout=@layout/fragment2 -->
        </fragment>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment3"
            android:name="com.harshal.fragments.Fragment3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="373dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <!-- Preview: layout=@layout/mainchart -->
        </fragment>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what you want ?you want to change fragment2 to fragment3...???

Comment: sorry for confusion i want to make user able to interchange the positions of both fragments in runtime i.e. fragment1 at fragment2 and fragment2 at fragment1

Answer (score 0):

```
private void stackAFragmentPresc() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Fragment f;
            f = new PrescribeFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.main_details_fragment_container, f);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }
```

try with this code,
here PrescribeFragment() is ur fragmnet class.
and (main_details_fragment_container) this one is ur id in xml.
Hope this is useful to you.
thanks